# How far do we go to help users who don't seem to understand?

Tags: discussion

Today I noticed this question posted, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10280938/zendframework-comments-box, which looked familiar and on checking the user I found the exact same question posted earlier [Zend Framework comments box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10214923/zend-framework-comments-box).

As you can see I had a bit of a chat in comments trying to point him in the right direction (after flagging as a dup). I thought I was getting somewhere when he told me he had restructured the question. I expected to see an edit on the original question, but found this instead! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10282186/zendframework-using-same-variable-twice-causing-null-value

Apparently its not the same question if you change the title.

Should I give up on him?

Comment: I really don't get the point of this question. If you're tired of dealing with him, stop dealing with him. If you want to keep helping, go for it. What else is there?

Comment: Well, how far do you *want* to go? Of course you're required to be polite, and providing assistance to new users is the right thing to do, but there is no mandated level of hand-holding. That would be silly.

Comment: I just needed to vent :) I've done all I can.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Keep explaining and flagging (till utter frustration sets in - at this point **just let go**).

Some users don't seem to want to understand how to work within the SE framework - if the user continues with this behavior, their posts will get flagged over and over and the moderators will resort to banning them.

Apart from trying to educate such users (and flagging their posts), there isn't much one can do.

Comment: Don't forget our friend the question-ban if he accumulates too many downvoted/deleted questions.

Comment: @Kobobby - I'm eagerly awaiting the forthcoming "Help, I'm getting sorry, we're no longer accepting ..." question on meta.